# Notification and AlarmManager

Tags: android

I know that this question has been asked several times but I really don't understand why my code doesn't work. I based upon a lot of examples (from stackoverflow answers) to write my code and I need help to understand where is the problem.

**The context**

The user can, trough preferences, choose a day to be notify.
I get a number from 2 (monday) 3...4...5... to 1 (sunday).

```
public Calendar getCalendar(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,getDayForNotification());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

    return calendar;
}
```

Then I want to repeat the alarm once a week on the day that the user has chosen.

```
public void setNotificationDate() {

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, myAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    DateNotificationPreference dateNotificationPreference = new DateNotificationPreference(this);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, dateNotificationPreference.getCalendar().getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, alarmIntent);

}
```

My broadcast receiver

```
public class myAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
    Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    context.startService(service1);

   }
}
```

In my service, I have juste one method :

```
public void createNotification(){
    final NotificationManager mNotification = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    final Intent launchNotifiactionIntent = new Intent(this, mySilhouette.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, launchNotifiactionIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
            .setContentTitle("my notification")
            .setContentText("my first notification")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    mNotification.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

When I choose the current day, the notification appears at the good time, but when I relaunch the app at 8:05 am for example, I have again a notification. After that, if I choose another day and go back to the activity, I have again a notification...There is something strange and I don't know what can be the problem. I need your help :)

Thanks a lot !

Kmel

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to check if you are dealing with past or future dates?

Comment: I tried several solutions but I do not succeed to manage it. Even if I do the check, the notification is send several times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set()` on `Calendar` does just that: it sets the value. As a result, the date may be in the past, given your existing code.

For example, where I am, right now it is Friday. So, the object returned by `Calendar.getInstance()` is set for now, which means its day-of-week will be Friday. If you call `set()` to change that to Tuesday, now you may be setting a date in the past. Similarly, even if you were to set the day-of-week to Friday, it is after 8am where I am, and therefore you would be creating a date that is in the past.

You need to check your calculated `Calendar` object and see if it is in the past. If it is, add 7 days to move it to the *next* week's time for the alarm to go off.

Also, note that an `RTC` alarm will not wake up the device out of sleep mode. That may be fine for your purposes, but I just wanted to make sure that you were aware of this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand now the result of Calendar. I thought that `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7` would be sufficient to move to the next week's time ?

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to understand the interest to use an alarm if I need to manage past day or futur day and so on...I thought that I had just to set the day I want to be notify and the alarm manager will manage, I want to say, the right moment defined by the user to notify him... :-)