# How To Repeat Alarm On Wednesday at 1pm (Once a week) In Android

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

In my android application, I have a UI that lets users select the day [1-7] of the week (Sunday - Saturday) and a time of day for that particular day.

Once they have selected those two items, I want to create an alarm that goes off repeatedly on that day [**just once a week**]. So, this alarm only fires once a week.

So far, I have written this piece of code to try and get that working - I am not sure I have gotten it right because it does not fire:

```
private void setAlarmClock(){
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, [userSelectedDay]);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, [userSelectedTime]);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, [userSelectedMinutes]);

    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also, how would I play a sound to actually alert the users?

So far, all SO questions that I have read through weren't helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With respect to your `Calendar`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710968/notification-and-alarmmanager/29711065#29711065). Also, `setInexactRepeating()` is inexact and will not fire at your requested time in all likelihood, but sometime around it. With respect to the sound, while you could play a ringtone as nana suggests, you are *much* better off raising a `Notification`. Otherwise, if the user is not within earshot of the phone at the time of the event, they will not know it happened. Also, they may forget what the ringtone means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play the default alarm sound like this for example:

```
Uri alarmTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
Ringtone ringtoneAlarm = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alarmTone);
ringtoneAlarm.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
ringtoneAlarm.play();
```

Now as [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) states, when using [setInexactRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) you have to use one of the internal [constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#constants):

- **INTERVAL_DAY**
- **INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES**
- **INTERVAL_HALF_DAY**
- **INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR**
- **INTERVAL_HOUR**

So if you want to repeat in a week (or any other non-standard interval) you will have to use [`setRepeating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) instead.

Comment: Very much appreciate it nana!

Comment: Ofcourse! Did it answer your queton or did I miss something?

Comment: nana, sorry I forgot to mark it - I owe you a yellow circle

Comment: :) No need to be sorry, I just wasn't sure if I should add something. Thanks.